# How to integrate payment portal in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm working on cakephp project & want to add paypal payment portal in my project.
Can anyone help me out to integrate paypal payment portal

Comment: What did you try so far ? A Google search returns various cakePHP PayPal integrations ready to use:
https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=paypal%20cakephp

Comment: You can follow the instructions in one of the plugins:
https://github.com/robmcvey/cakephp-paypal